# angular's $http.get() receives status -1 while it should receive status 401

Tags: angularjs, http, oauth-2.0, cors, http-status-code-401

I have a strange problem... We have a server protected with oauth, when it returns 401 (token expired for example) angular receives a status -1. However, when a valid token is used, everything is fine.

The options request:

```
Request URL: [server].../forms/[id]
Request Method:OPTIONS
Status Code:200 
Remote Address:52.212.120.132:80

Access-Control-Allow-Headers:authorization
Access-Control-Allow-Methods:GET,OPTIONS,DELETE,PUT,HEAD,POST
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
Access-Control-Max-Age:1800
Allow:GET, HEAD, POST, PUT, DELETE, TRACE, OPTIONS, PATCH
Cache-Control:no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
```

The real call:

```
Request URL: [server].../forms/[id]
Request Method:GET
Status Code:401 
Remote Address:52.212.120.132:80


Content-Type:application/json;charset=UTF-8
Server:nginx/1.11.6
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
WWW-Authenticate:Bearer realm="oauth2-resource", error="invalid_token", error_description="Token expired"
```

But in angular, a status -1 is received in the error callback.

I do get a CORS issue in the console:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load [server].../forms/[id]. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:9000' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 401.
```

But, as you can see, 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the OPTIONS request, and the real call is actually done.

Does someone have any ideas? Any advice or direction would be welcome!

Comment: _" 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the OPTIONS request"_ But not in the response to the actual request.

Comment: So basically: the server's CORS-filter happens after the Authentication-filter?

Comment: The cors need to be changed in the backend, which seems it is rails. You need to add http://localhost:9000 as an exception..I had a similar problem and solved,  if it is indeed rails let me know so I can post my solution...

Comment: Java with spring, and CORS is OK, happy flow calls have no issues, but I guess the order of the filters is wrong. Simple solution would be to put CORS on the server level instead of on application level